# Spring Boot WebMvc unit test date error: perform() returned date is earlier than expected(due to GMT assumption)

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, jackson, mockito

I am using Spring Boot Test framework + Mockito to do controller unit testing. I find the test fails due to a strange error: when I tell Mockito to return an object with `java.util.Date` field, the response always has a date string one day earlier than expected.

My test is like this:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.controller;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.not;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import com.privalia.binlookup.model.BinInfo;
import com.privalia.binlookup.repo.BinInfoRepository;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.MOCK, properties="classpath:test.properties")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure=false)
public class BinInfoControllerUnitTests {
    @InjectMocks
    private BinInfoController controller;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private BinInfoRepository repository;

    private BinInfo mockBinInfo;

    @Before
    public void init() throws ParseException{
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
        this.mockBinInfo = new BinInfo();
        this.mockBinInfo.setId(new Long(42));
        this.mockBinInfo.setBin("touhou");
        this.mockBinInfo.setJson_full("{is_json:true}");
        this.mockBinInfo.setCreateAt(fmt.parse("18/08/2018"));
    }


    @Test
    public void testBinInfoControllerSearchBIN() throws Exception {
        when(this.repository.findByBin("touhou")).thenReturn(mockBinInfo);

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/search/touhou")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
            .andExpect(content().string(not("")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.bin", is("touhou")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.json_full", is("{is_json:true}")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.createAt", is("18/08/2018")));
    }
}
```

And my controller is:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.controller;

import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.privalia.binlookup.model.BinInfo;
import com.privalia.binlookup.repo.BinInfoRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class BinInfoController {

    @Autowired
    private BinInfoRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value="/search/{bin}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<BinInfo> searchBIN(@Valid @PathVariable String bin) {
        BinInfo found = repository.findByBin(bin);
        BodyBuilder builder = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK);
        builder.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
        return (found == null ? builder.body(null) : builder.body(found));
    }

}
```

The test fails, because the returned `createAt` string is `17/08/2018`, not `18/08/2018`.

I am in timezone "Madrid/Europe (GMT +0200, CEST)" because we are in summer and with DST(Daylight saving time), and I suspect some timezone stuff is interfering.

My guess:

**The mock object has a `java.util.Date` object without timezone information, and is the 00:00 of 18 of August; when passed the Spring context or Jackson or Mockito in `perform()`, the JSON parsed is considered GMT, thus is minus 2 hours, thus back to 17 of August.**

but I don't know where to find the related configuration, whether to tell Jackson, or to Spring, or Mockito **not** to do the conversion.

EDIT:

Cause confirmed: when I change the date string to `18/08/2018 02:00:00`, the returned date is `18/08/2018 00:00:00`.

Answer (score 0):

After some real struggling, I find that I have to use `OffsetDateTime` on my entity datetime fields, and in PostgreSQL I have to use `timestamptz`(timestamp with timezone). Also, the datetime string to parse must have timezone info.

Bean field:

```
@NotNull
@Column(name="updated_at", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
// Formats output date when this DTO is passed through JSON
@JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z")
// Allows date to be passed into GET request in JSON
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z")
@JsonProperty("updatedAt")
/**
 * A timestamp object representing the moment the bininfo is updated.
 * In database we store the value with UTC timestamp, timestamptz.
 * When we save, local time will be converted to UTC, and when retrieve,
 * the offset is handled automatically.
 */
private OffsetDateTime updatedAt;
```

Object construction for testing:

```
private String format; // 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z'

private String dateString; // '18/08/2018 02:00:00 +0200'

@Before
public void init() throws ParseException{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    this.mockBinInfo = new BinInfo();
    this.mockBinInfo.setId(new Long(42));
    this.mockBinInfo.setBin("touhou");
    this.mockBinInfo.setJson_full(this.json_full);
    this.mockBinInfo.setBrand(this.brand);
    this.mockBinInfo.setType(this.type);
    this.mockBinInfo.setCountry(this.country);
    this.mockBinInfo.setIssuer(this.issuer);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format);
    OffsetDateTime d = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
    this.mockBinInfo.setCreatedAt(d);
    this.mockBinInfo.setUpdatedAt(d);
}
```

PostgreSQL table column definition:

```
updated_at | timestamp with time zone |
```

And the saved value:

```
test1=# select * from bin_info;
| .. |       updated_at
+----+------------------------
| .. | 2018-08-18 00:00:00+02
```

Note that in my JSON, the timestamp is `02:00:00 +0200`(localtime with timezone offset), in DB is saved as `00:00:00+02`(GMT with offset). I haven't change JVM timezone/locale/country settings.